# Problems with running Python code in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following issue https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/questions/68282/elektron-real-time-in-cloud-connection-errors-usin.html?childToView=68304#answer-68304

And there is said that I should run following code
`python.exe market_price_edpgw_authentication.py --hostname emea-1.pricing.streaming.edp.thomsonreuters.com --user YourMachine --clientid YourMachine --password YourPassword`

This comes from: https://github.com/Refinitiv/websocket-api/blob/master/Applications/Examples/RDP/python/market_price_edpgw_authentication.py:

I have Python 3.7 and PyCharm and do not understand how run this command. I downloaded this python file to desktop, then started new project in PyCharm and then in PyCharm wrote this code and nothing appeared in the output.
Could you help on how to run it?

Comment: You need to describe your problem within the question itself. Links can/will die

Answer (score 1):

You can open `market_price_edpgw_authentication.py`, then go to the Run Configurations window to add program arguments for

`--hostname emea-1.pricing.streaming.edp.thomsonreuters.com --user YourMachine --clientid YourMachine --password YourPassword`

Otherwise, you don't need Pycharm if you don't plan on editing this file

The "code" you've shown is meant to be used in CMD / Powershell